# Samsung phone with PRELOADED Google items - "Google Play Services keeps stopping" popping up on phone. Have used help centre!

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

**Tried all ways within Google Help Centre** to correct this problem.  Google Play Services now shows **"Disabled" and "Force Stop" buttons now both greyed out** and cannot rectify this latest problem.  Also **Google Play Store App will not open at all** to show available app.  I don't want to lose any information from my Samsung phone, so I have loaded photos to computer and made a written list of my contacts.
Any help please to rectify the problems with Google on my phone.

Comment: Thank you but no longer require assistance. Have been advised to delete Google Account and reinstate.

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!